# How to convert a change log into a weekly record

Tags: sql, mysql, snapshot

This is pretty specific, but basically I have a history of a property being changed

| Value | Change Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | May 8 |
| 10000 | May 10 |

And I want to create a weekly snapshot view that shows me

May 8 - 2000
May 15 - 10000

I have created a table that gives me Weekly dates like so,
May 1
May 8
May 15
...

And I have tried to join that table onto my table that has the history of changes where the Weekly Date >= the change date, but I end up with duplicate records like

May 8 - 2000
May 15 - 2000
May 15 - 10000

-- what is the best way to "replace" the previous value with the updated value so I end up with a "Snapshot" view?

This is difficult to explain so LMK if anyone has any questions. Appreciate the help in advance

Comment: Did you mean to group your history data into weekly report using  days between a weekly date (inclusive) and its previous weekly date (exclusive) ?

Comment: So for each date in your week table you want the most recent value on it before that date?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how to lag the data? Something like this might work:

```
SELECT 
    WeeklyDate,
    COALESCE(Value, LAG(Value) OVER (ORDER BY ChangeDate)) AS SnapshotValue
FROM 
    --[enter your table name]
ORDER BY 
    ChangeDate;
```

This assumes your data is sorted by the Change Date in ascending order; this is important for the LAG() function to work correctly.

Using the LAG() function to get the previous value (if the current value is not null, use it, if it is null, use the previous value) via the coalesce function.